# Construct well-defined bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let $\mathcal{C}_X\cong\mathcal{C}_n$ be the monoid of self-maps $\alpha$ of $X=\{1\dots,n\}$ that are order-preserving ($\forall x,y$, $x\le y$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha(x)\le\alpha(y)$) and decreasing ($\forall x$, $\alpha(x)\le x$).

Let N($\mathcal{C_n})$ be all nilpotent elements of $\mathcal{C}_n$, i.e., those $\alpha\in\mathcal{C}_n$ such that some power of $\alpha$ equals the absorbing element (the constant function $1$.)

We say $a(\in\mathcal{C}_n$) $r$-nilpotent if $r$ is the smallest positive integer satisfying $a^r=0$. Then I guess that there is a well-defined bijection 
$a\mathcal{C}_na\to N(\mathcal{C}_r)$.
Although I have tried many times, I could not construct it.

Comment: What is your definition of $r$-nilpotent?

Comment: $a^r=0$.  $0$ is the constant map to $1$ for self monoid.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you think a bijection should exist. Do you know if the two sets have the same cardinality? Is there an algebraic or combinatorial argument that points to such a bijection? Does it exist at least when $r$ and $n$ are small?

Comment: Don't you want to have $r$ being the *smallest* $r$ such that $a^r =0$? Otherwise, if you take $r = 2$ and $a = 0$, you would get $aC_na= \{0\} = N({\cal C}_2)$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin if $a=0$, then $r=1$. Because $a^1=0$.  if $a$ is $1$ or $2$-nilpotent then   then it is clear that $a\mathcal{C}_na$ have only one element.

Comment: But since $0^2 = 0$, $0$ is also $2$-nilpotent, according to your definition.

Comment: Thank you. I added the definition of $r$-nilpotent in question. Actually, I research local   subsemigroup and variants of $\mathcal{C}_n$.  I  awared of  this some unexpected observations.

Comment: I find a counter-example. Let $a=\left( \begin{array}{cccccc} 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\ 1  & 1  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5\end{array}\right)$. Then the cardinality of $aC_na$ is $3$, but the cardinality of $N(C_3)$ is $2$.

Comment: Is it possible the calculate the cardinality of $aC_na$ for  $r$-nilpotent $a$?